# d3 insert vs append in context of creating nodes on mousemove

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In the following code, the author uses .insert to position circles "before" the rectangle (in reality they appear over the top I believe) rather than appending them directly to the svg space.

I thought this unnecessary so removed the rect and the .insert and appended the circle elements directly to the svg space. However the result is that the circles don't 'draw fast enough' (for lack of a more articulate explanation).

Can anyone either explain why this is happening to me or point me in the direction of some literature that does explain it?

```
var width = Math.max(900, innerWidth),
    height = Math.max(700, innerHeight)

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr({
        "width": width,
        "height": height
    })

var i = 1;

svg.append("rect")
    .attr({
        "width": width,
        "height": height
    })
    .on("mousemove", particle)

function particle() {
    var m = d3.mouse(this)

    var circle = svg.insert("circle", "rect")
        .attr("cx", m[0])
        .attr("cy", m[1])
        .attr("r", 10)
        .style("stroke", d3.hsl((i = (i + 1) % 360), 1, .5))
        .style("stroke-opacity", 1)
        .transition().duration(1000)
        .ease(Math.sqrt)
        .attr("r", 100)
        .style("stroke-opacity", 1e-6)
}
```

Thanks and credit to http://techslides.com/over-1000-d3-js-examples-and-demos.

I've created a jsfiddle @ http://jsfiddle.net/hiwilson1/mgchrm0w/

Comment: i'm not sure whats the problem with this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/s9767kw2/ ?

Comment: The fiddle doesn't work for me, but thats neither here nor there. The question is really how the mechanics behind .insert and .append function differently to enable the circles to be drawn fluently and consistently with .insert but not with .append.

Comment: thats why i linked to the fiddle. its with insert and without rect, and as far as i can tell it's working ok

Comment: I mislead you above - I didn't actually remove the rect I just changed the line of code @ var circle = svg.insert("circle", "rect") to var circle = svg.append("circle"). Moving the on("mousemove") event to the svg space as well as changing this line of code has cleared up the performance issues to an extent. When I go full screen though it's definitely a little more sluggish than using insert("circle", "rect") and the author must've chosen that method for a reason...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As pointed out by @altocumulus, it's simply that the strokes of the appended discs tend to block the `rect` from receiving `mouseover` events.  You can exaggerate the effect by adding fill to the circles.  So, that's why `insert()` performs better than `append()`.

The other way to make append work is to put the listener on the `svg` element and take advantage of event bubbling.  Both `rect` and `circle` `mouseover` events will bubble up to the parent svg.

You can see all this by fiddling around with this...

```js
        var width = Math.max(900, innerWidth),
            height = Math.max(700, innerHeight),

            svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                .attr('id', 'svg')
                .attr({
                    "width": width,
                    "height": height
                })

            i = 1, c = 0,
            method = document.getElementById('metod'),
            fill = document.getElementById('fill'),
            remove = document.getElementById('remove'),

            SelectGroup = function (selectId, onUpdate) {

                var _selectedOptionById = function (id) {
                    var _node = document.getElementById(id);
                    return  function () {
                        return _node[_node.selectedIndex]
                    }
                },

                _selectedOption = _selectedOptionById(selectId);

                return {
                    update: function () {
                        onUpdate.apply(_selectedOption(), arguments)
                    },
                }
            },

            mouseListenerSelector = SelectGroup ('mouseListenerSelector',  function onUpdate (event, listener) {
                //this: selected option node
                //the node 'on' and 'off' attributes are selectors for the event listeners
                //enable the 'on' listener and remove the off listener
                var _selected = this,
                    switchOn = d3.select(_selected.getAttribute('on')),
                    switchOff = d3.select(_selected.getAttribute('off'));

                switchOn.on(event, listener);
                switchOff.on(event, null);
            }),

            rectEventsAuto = document.getElementById('rectEventsAuto'),
            //rectEventsAuto = document.getElementById('rectEventsAuto'),
            
            rect = svg.append("rect")
                .attr('id', 'rect')
                .attr({
                    "width": width,
                    "height": height
                })

            d3.select('#options').on('change', function () {

                svg.selectAll('circle').remove()
                applyListener(mouseListenerSelector, rectEventsAuto.value)

            })


            function applyListener(mouseListenerSelector, rectEventsAuto) {

                if (rectEventsAuto) {
                    rect.attr('style', null)
                } else {
                    rect.attr('style', 'pointer-events: all;')
                }

                mouseListenerSelector.update("mousemove.circles", particle)
                mouseListenerSelector.update(("ontouchstart" in document ? "touchmove" : "mousemove") + ".circles", particle)
            }

            applyListener(mouseListenerSelector, rectEventsAuto.value)


        function particle() {
            var m = d3.mouse(this),

                circle = svg[method.value]("circle", "rect")
                .attr("cx", m[0])
                .attr("cy", m[1])
                .attr("r", 10)
                .style("stroke", d3.hsl((i = (i + 1) % 360), 1, .5))
                .style("stroke-opacity", 1)
                .style("fill", fill.value == 'solid' ? d3.hsl((i = (i + 1) % 360), 1, .5) : fill.value)
                .transition().duration(1000)
                .ease(Math.sqrt)
                .attr("r", 100)
            //.style("stroke-opacity", 1e-6)

            if (remove.value) { circle.remove() }
        }
```

```css
body {
            margin: 0;
            background: #222;
            min-width: 960px;
        }

        rect {
            fill: none;
            pointer-events: all;
        }

        circle {
            fill: none;
            stroke-width: 2.5px;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
    <div id="options">
        <select id="metod">
            <option value="insert">insert</option>
            <option value="append" selected="selected">append</option>
        </select>
        <select id="fill">
            <option value="solid" selected="selected">solid</option>
            <option value="none">no fill</option>
        </select>
        <select id="remove">
            <option value="true">remove</option>
            <option value="" selected="selected">don't remove</option>
        </select>
        <select id="mouseListenerSelector">
            <option value="true" on ="svg" off="rect">listener on svg</option>
            <option value="" selected="selected" on="rect" off="svg">listener on rect</option>
        </select>
        <select id="rectEventsAuto">
            <option value="true" selected="selected">pointer-events null; on rect</option>
            <option value="">pointer-events: all; on rect</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: I wasn't sure why we were appending a rect at all - I didn't see why we couldn't just add a mousemove event to the svg space but @altocumulus has pointed out that the svg element may have mouse events defined in future which would cause a conflict in any code I wrote now.
Thanks for the example and your elaborate explanation.

Comment: @hwilson1 no worries mate, thanks for the question, I'm still learning this stuff so I'm on the look-out for good study questions.  Not sure there is a problem with event collisions, events can be name-spaced in d3, like `mousemove.circles`, `mousemove.otherStuff` so that shouldn't be a problem....

Comment: If you want another good study question I'd appreciate if you could take a look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29632287/d3-multi-foci-force-key-code-component-understanding. Posted yesterday, no suggestions to an explanation as of yet.

Answer (score 3):

To me there is no real difference in performance between both methods even in fullscreen mode. I think the reason for choosing `insert()` over `append()` is rather a matter of handling mouse events. The SVG 1.1 spec states on [hit-testing](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/interact.html#hit-testing):

> This specification does not define the behavior of pointer events on
>   the rootmost ‘svg’ element for SVG images which are embedded by
>   reference or inclusion within another document, e.g., whether the
>   rootmost ‘svg’ element embedded in an HTML document intercepts mouse
>   click events; future specifications may define this behavior, but for
>   the purpose of this specification, the behavior is
>   implementation-specific.

Inserting circles before the `<rect>` ensures that the `<rect>` will always be rendered on top all circles. Furthermore, setting `pointer-events: all` on the `<rect>` will set it as the first target to receive any mouse events. This way you'll have a clean implementation not relying on *implementation-specific* behaviour of the user agent rendering the embedded svg.

Comment: So if I wrote code now that had a mousemove event on the svg element, that may conflict with future specifications in which mousemove event may correspond to something entirely different?

"Inserting circles before the <rect> ensures that it will always be rendered on top of all circles" - so ensuring it's always on top means clicking anywhere will always be clicking on the circle? 

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: 1. Today's SVG 1.1 spec leaves it to the user agent whether or not the rootmost svg may be the target of mouse events. Future versions may explicitely permit or deny targeting mouse events to the rootmost svg. This *might* break your code in future implementations of user agents. 2. Elements in svg are rendered in document order. If the circles are inserted before the `<rect>` they are rendered beneath it. Thus, the rectangle above them will be the first target of the mouse event.

Comment: What's a user agent? Is that the browser? So Google, Microsoft etc might determine specific events to occur on svg space in future versions of their browsers?

Comment: See the spec for a definition of a [user agent](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/intro.html#TermUserAgent). It may be a browser or a standalone application for rendering and displaying svgs.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell from the docs:

- https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_append
- https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_insert

Insert should, if anything, be a bit slower than append, as it seems to need some additional checks in case the before selector doesn't match anything.

Other than that, I concur with the comment left by @user3906922 that judging from the 2 fiddles, there doesn't seem to be much differnce in performance between the two.

Comment: Thanks for the links. I'm sure there's something going on behind the scenes that motivated the author to choose the .insert method over the .append method and as I said in my response to user3906922 above there's definitely a slight performance detriment at full screen using .append over .insert although it's now negligible.

Comment: Whatever motivated him to choose insert over append, is not related directly to the performance of those methods. I created a jsPerf (http://jsperf.com/d3-insert-vs-append) to see if my intuition was correct, and in a straight comparison, .append is quite a bit faster than .insert, so if you are looking for a bottleneck, .append probably isn't it.